# How to configure gem5 simulator for SMART Microarchitecture

Tags: gem5

I am new to gem5 simulator, here I am trying to compare the results(simulation parameters) of the various architecture of NoC(like baseline, SMART). I am not able to configure the NoC in SMART architecture can someone tell me how to configure the simulator to support SMART architecture.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail? Are you sure gem5 implements those?